# Redis multiple persistence policies

Tags: redis

I was wondering whether it is possible to have a single Redis server instance having multiple active persistence policies.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have AOF on a set of keys and absolutely nothing on all other keys.

Is this doable? Or is having 2 Redis server instances listening on different sockets the only way?

Answer (score 5):

> Is this doable?

Nope.

> Or is having 2 redis-server instances listening on different sockets the only way?

Yep.

Comment: Just to add here, different persistence policy is not possible for different sets of keys because the persistence policy is defined in the redif.conf which is per server, not per set of keys.